# Что вычисляет данная функция?

Tags: c++, разработка-игр

В общем, имеется 6 float координат в игре:
PlayerPos_X, PlayerPos_Z, PlayerPos_Y и еще 3 (я так и не узнал что это)
Pos_X, Pos_Z, Pos_Y
Суть такова, есть байты данных, которые передаются в игре на сервер, не могу понять за что отвечают вторые три координаты, первые три координаты - это позиция игрока на карте, вторые три координаты по значению очень близки к позиции игрока, но не равны (вторые координаты генерируются во время атаки, в зависимости от направления куда атакуешь в 3D пространстве). Вообще, данные координаты относятся как то к атаке (то-ли смещения взгляда, то ли вектор куда игрок атакует).
На сервере есть вот такая функция, собственно, с помощью нее и можем выяснить что за вторые координаты: Pos_X, Pos_Z, Pos_Y:

```
float res_x = Pos_X - PlayerPos_X;
float res_z = Pos_Z - PlayerPos_Z;
float res_y = Pos_Y - PlayerPos_Y;
float result = atan2f(res_x, res_y) * 57.295776 * 0.5;
if(result < 0.0) 
    result = result + 180.0

int viewoffset = result;
```

Код примерно такой как указано сверху, одно понятно точно, оно вычисляет смещение взгляда игрока, однако, что в таком случае вторые 3 координаты? Это смещение камеры или что?
Разъясните что тут происходит, он исходя из координат игрока на карте и вектора куда атакует игрок получает смещение его взгляда чтобы потом понять находится ли моб в диапазоне viewoffset с разницей в -30 и +30, то есть получается мобы которые попадают в диапазон между этими значениями viewoffset будут задамажены?
Правильно ли я всё понял?

Answer (score 2):

z компонента координаты не используется в примере совсем. 57.295776 это 180 деленное на пи.

поэтому, atan2f(res_x, res_y) - вычисляет угол в радианах между двух векторов, умножив на 57.3 получим в градусах. Зачем там умножают на 0.5 - не знаю, может там что то ещё есть. Сама функция atan2f возвращает в диапазоне [-pi, +pi], поэтому там и прибавляют 180, что бы перевести в диапазон от 0 до 360, но из за умножения, получается от нуля до 90 и от 180 до 270. Такой себе крест-накрест. Где там Ваше -30 +30 - не знаю.

Скорее всего - Posx - это координаты его оружия.

Comment: +30 и -30 там в другом месте, в общем, эта функция сама служит для определения в какую сторону атакует игрок мечем
Я не знаю почему там * 0.5, в гугле смог найти тока константу 57.295776

Comment: @Дан: В смысле? В Гугле найти `0.5` не удалось? `0.5`, конечно, очень редкая константа, в отличие от известного даже младенцу `57.295776`, но и она должна а Гугле встречаться....

Comment: Дело в том, что в этой игре при перемещении игрока передается Direction (куда смотрит игрок), она не в 360 градусах, там используется 1 байт для хранения Direction, если память не изменяет, в игре не 360 градусов используется для определения куда направлен взгляд игрока, а используется всего 180, то бишь, 0 - 90 - это когда игрок смотрит в противоположную сторону от 0, еще + 90 - это 0
Итого получаем что в игре используется только 180 градусов, для поворта на 360 градусов.
Что думаете? Это как то связано с * 0.5 ?
Сейчас я проверю еще разок, чтоб сказать точно, до 180 там или выше

Comment: @KoVadim: Потестил в общем, используется 1 байт в игре для смещения взгляда, использует числа от 0 до -77
Получается что если игрок изначально смотрит вверх, то его смещение взгляда = 0, если повернуть его вправо, получаем 45 градусов, вниз = 90 градусов, влево = -121, вверх = 0, но если повернуть на 1 градус влево относительно 0 взгляда, то получим -77, другими словами if(Dir == -76) то обнуляем взгляд и все по новой. Получается что от 0  до 90 - это полукруг справой сторону, а левы полукруг от 90 до -77
Я не пойму почему в игре такая система смещений, а не 360 градусов, это как то связано?

Comment: Как я понял, если посчитать 0 до 127, а потом прибавить разницу от -128 до -76, то получим 180 в итоге, что думаете?